# How to parse cmd.exe values ​in NSIS?

Tags: c#, nsis

In cmd.exe, type Generator.exe param1 param2 param3 and tell me how to parse the received value.

Generator is an exe created in C #.

Result class and main part were edited slightly. I want to do NSIS string parsing on Result value.

```
static void Main(string[] param)
{
        // ip, key, productName
        if (param.Length != 3)
        {
            CResult result = new CResult();
            result.Result = false;
            result.Msg = "IP or Key NULL";
            Console.WriteLine(result.Result.ToString() + ',' + result.Msg);
            return;
        }
}
public class CResult
{
    private bool _result = false;


    public bool Result
    {
        get { return _result; }
        set { _result = value; }
    }

    private string _msg = "WORK_FAIL";


    public string Msg
    {
        get { return _msg; }
        set { _msg = value; }
    }


    public int nRet { get; set; }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uka0x.png)

As shown in the figure, in NSIS, I want to put a message box in the parsing syntax called False in the IF statement.

Comment: If Generator.exe is a C# program, how is this NSIS related?

Comment: Is this any help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/command-line-arguments

Comment: @Anders 
I can not speak English very well. 

Generator.exe issues a license after validating the specific IP through WebRequest.Therefore, it returns the result value. For example, the Result CLASS value is True and license Success. 
I will edit the Result class again.

Comment: @ Robin Bennett 
I do not think so. I have explained the question in more detail.

Comment: Parse the value as what? If you cant explain in english, demonstrate with examples, show an input, show the desired output, what you tried and what is the output you are now getting.

Comment: @Mat J 
I attached the picture. The cmd result is the second line, and I want to use NSIS parsing for the result.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to parse the stdout text?

Comment: @Anders 
I'm sorry, but I do not know what stdout is doing. I am sorry to say the same thing. Depending on the result of cmd, NSIS would like to pop up a message box.
If the result is False as shown in the picture, the IP or key null value should appear in the NSIS message box.

Comment: Console.WriteLine writes to stdout. Using the process exit code would remove the need to actually parse the string (Main() can return a int).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nsExec (or one of the other exec plug-ins) if you need to capture the output written to stdout by a console program:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

Section
nsExec::ExecToStack '"$InstDir\Generator.exe" param1 param2 param3'
Pop $0 ; Exit code
Pop $1 ; Output
${If} $1 == "string goes here"
  MessageBox mb_Ok "Message text!"
  Abort
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

If the output contains newlines you can include those in your string check:

```
Section
nsExec::ExecToStack '"cmd.exe" /c echo.Hello'
Pop $0 ; Exit code
Pop $1 ; Output

${If} $1 = "Hello$\r$\n"
    MessageBox mb_OK "Hi"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

or you can remove the newlines:

```
!include StrFunc.nsh
${StrTrimNewLines}

Section
nsExec::ExecToStack '"cmd.exe" /c echo.Hello'
Pop $0 ; Exit code
Pop $1 ; Output

${StrTrimNewLines} $1 $1
${If} $1 = "Hello"
    MessageBox mb_OK "Hi"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: thx very much.
I'll try it tomorrow. I have a headache because of NSIS .. 
Can you help me with other questions? 
Is there a way to create a folder in the root of NSIS and install it before $ InstDir (before installing files)?

Comment: You can create a directory yes but you should ask a new question. And please try to take some extra time to explain what you are trying to do and what the result should be when asking a question.

Comment: I can not debug in nsis, so I guess I used trim.

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: A little debugging tips, if you are not getting a string match, look at the string with `MessageBox mb_Ok "|$0|"`. It will show you if there are newlines.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the String value received from the console, but I could not use it.
I checked for whitespace and newline characters.
I do not know why. But It was used normally when I put in the portion of Trim processing in NSIS.

```
Function Trim
Exch $R1 ; Original string
Push $R2
Loop:
    StrCpy $R2 "$R1" 1
    StrCmp "$R2" " " TrimLeft
    StrCmp "$R2" "$\r" TrimLeft
    StrCmp "$R2" "$\n" TrimLeft
    StrCmp "$R2" "$\t" TrimLeft
    GoTo Loop2
TrimLeft:
    StrCpy $R1 "$R1" "" 1
    Goto Loop
Loop2:
    StrCpy $R2 "$R1" 1 -1
    StrCmp "$R2" " " TrimRight
    StrCmp "$R2" "$\r" TrimRight
    StrCmp "$R2" "$\n" TrimRight
    StrCmp "$R2" "$\t" TrimRight
    GoTo Done
TrimRight:
    StrCpy $R1 "$R1" -1
    Goto Loop2
Done:
    Pop $R2
    Exch $R1
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: This is not really the answer, you just posted a trim function without context. I can add the trim part to my answer.